# generating random numbers using an unbiased coin

Tags: probability

I have a question in which I need to generate random numbers in the range 0-9 by means of an unbiased coin such that it is equally likely to get any number. Since there is no limit on the number of coin tosses I first tried to do it like this:

1. Do 10 coin tosses.
2. If a head appears in the nth coin toss, then generate that number. I.e if 
   the sequence is 0000000001, then generate 0, if 0000000010 then generate 1 and so on. I defined this as my random variable

This method does give an equal probability of (1/2) ^ 10 but the sum of all 10 events does (while calculating the probability mass function) not sum up to one.

Then afterwards I tried to do it by defining the random variable as the appearance of consecutive heads. So if, consecutive heads = 1, then generate 0, if consecutive heads = 2, then generate the number 2 and so on. This maps to a binomial distribution, and even though it sums up to 1, the probability of getting each number is different.

Is there any way I could do this, or could anyone please give me a hint on how to approach this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: It' impossible to accomplish the task without discarding events, in my opinion, because $2^n$ is never a multiple of $10$. Anyway you discard too much: you can do with only 4 tosses, considering the outcome as a binary number.

Comment: As a (minor) variant to the suggestion in the prior comment, you could do $5$ tosses...the advantage being that you only need to discard $2$ cases, whereas with $4$ tosses you must discard $6$.

Comment: @Aretino If I discard the 10, 11, 12, 13,  14, and 15 binary won't these events be no longer a part of the sample space?

Comment: @lulu 2 cases because I could something like map 00000 and 00001 to 0, 00010 and 00011 to 1 and so on? So, 30 binary numbers could be mapped on 10 decimal ones, leaving the two? edit: sorry, meant three binary numbers to each decimal one, so 00000, 00001 and 00010 to 0 and so on.

Comment: Exactly.  This way you get a result $\frac {30}{32}=93.75\%$ of the time, whereas with $4$ tosses you only get a result $\frac {10}{16}=62.5\%$ of the time.

Comment: If you don't like to discard cases, you can build up an "infinite" binary decimal, stopping when it is clear that your number falls between $\frac {i}{10}$ and $\frac {i+1}{10}$.  Of course it could theoretically equal $\frac {j}{10}$ for an arbitrarily long string.

Comment: @lulu Thanks! The one thing I don't understand with this approach is that why aren't the discarded events having no effect on the total probability of the other events. If we are discarding some events aren't we sort of not considering a part of the sample space.

Comment: Sure and, as a result, you could toss infinitely often without obtaining a decision, at least theoretically.  But all you need from your method is that $0$, $1$, ..., $10$ are each hit with equal probability and we have that.

Comment: @lulu Ah!! I get it a bit. But suppose if I never get any of these numbers and always end up getting a combination of heads and tails which is not being mapped to any number, won't the probability of each of these events become zero?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29341/discussion-between-lulu-and-qptr).

Comment: Please read [this](http://www.wou.edu/~snyderj/Biology%20357%20-%20Ecology/Laboratory%20Exercises/Ecology%20Lab%20%231/Biased%20Coin%20Flips.pdf) beautiful reference for some ideas.